# Select option calculation with switch case

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is have a drop down menu, select an option in this case I want 2 bottles of jwWhisky. I want it to then go to the js and have the switch case enter the price for the bottle and multiply it by the bottles I want.

The HTML:

```js
function calculate() {
  "use strict"
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('drinks1Num').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('drinks1Type').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  var inputCost = 0;
  switch (myBox2) {
    case 'jwWhisky':
      inputCost = 49;
      break
      //default:
      //  alert ("You haven't coded this yet");
  }

  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<legend>
  Sprits Option
</legend>
<select id="drinks1Num" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="drinks1Type" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option disabled="disabled"></option>
  <optgroup label="whisky">
    <option value="jwWhisky">Johnnie Walker 700ml</option>49$
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input id="result" />
```

Comment: presumably wait until after your switch determines your unit cost for the input (inputCost), then multiply that by myBox1 to get myResult.

Comment: hey ya, so go myBox1 * inputCost? if so. that did not work. i still get NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move the calculation of `myBox1 * inputCost` to after your switch:

```js
function calculate() {
        "use strict"
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('drinks1Num').value;   
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('drinks1Type').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var inputCost=0;
  
        switch (myBox2) {
            case 'jwWhisky':
                inputCost=49;
                break
            //default:
            //  alert ("You haven't coded this yet");
        }

        result.value = myBox1 * inputCost;
}
```

```html
<select id="drinks1Num" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="drinks1Type" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option disabled="disabled"></option>
  <optgroup label="whisky">
    <option value="jwWhisky">Johnnie Walker 700ml</option>49$
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input id="result" "/>
```

(Also, as you can see, you don't really need the `myResult` variable at all.)

Note that it would probably be nicer to just store the prices as `data-` attributes on each option element, as that would keep the product information together in one place in the HTML and you wouldn't need a JS switch statement. **EDIT** - Using one or more `data-` attributes lets you add additional information that will not be submitted with the form but which can be used for calculations in your JS, while the `value` attribute can still be used for the product code (and will be submitted). Perhaps something like this:

```js
function calculate() {
  "use strict";
  var num = document.getElementById('drinks1Num').value;   
        
  var drinkType = document.getElementById('drinks1Type');
  var unitCost = drinkType.options[drinkType.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-cost');

  document.getElementById('result').value = num * unitCost;
}
```

```html
<select id="drinks1Num" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="drinks1Type" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
  <option disabled="disabled"></option>
  <optgroup label="whisky">
    <option value="jwWhisky" data-cost="49">Johnnie Walker 700ml ($49)</option>
    <option value="something" data-cost="22">Something else ($22)</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input id="result" "/>
```

(Note also that in your original HTML you had `49$` *after* the closing `</option>` tag, so in the second version in my answer I've moved that into the text of the option element.)

Comment: Thank you so much!! haha ive spent hours today trying to solve this. hahah,. i cant beleive it. =( so simple now that i see it. im so gutted.

Comment: hey, how would i do that? sorry am still quiet new to this. the nicer the better though

Comment: I've added a simple example of that to my answer.

Comment: hye, thanks for your help =) it worked brilliantly. have added the data-cost. a lot more tidy. 

just have one more question though, 
var unitCost = drinkType.options[drinkType.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-cost')

im not sure what this part does. i know i need it. but not sure why

thanks for all your help

Comment: `drinkType` refers to the select element, `drinkType.options` refers to its collection of options, `drinkType.selectedIndex` is the index number of the currently selected option. So `drinkType.options[drinkType.selectedIndex]` gives you a reference to the currently selected option element, which we then call `.getAttribute()` on to retrieve that option's `data-cost`.

Comment: ah i see. thanks so much. that makes so much seance now =)